# Нужно ли было брать в кавычки причастие?

Tags: пунктуация, многозначность

*Захарова выразила уверенность, что даже малая часть конфискованного российского имущества не пойдёт на нужды жителей Украины, поскольку страна «пропитана» коррупцией.* (https://russian.rt.com)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147200/discussion-on-question-by-shampar-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

[пропитать](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/55267/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%CC%81%D1%82%D1%8C) (МАС)
|| *перен. (обычно в форме прич. страд. прош.). разг.* Пронизать, преисполнить чем-либо.
*Весь он [студент] был пропитан пылом своей молодой страсти к делу* (М. Горький. Супруги Орловы).

Думаю, что кавычки не нужны — причастие использовано в переносном значении, которое имеется в словарях.

Вот несколько примеров:
*В чем же смысл и логика этого страшного умозаключения? Что общество сверху донизу, насквозь **пропитано криминалом**?* (А. Ростовский. По законам волчьей стаи);
*Любому дураку понятно, что государство сверху донизу **пропитано ложью и коррупцией**...* (А. Ростовский. Русский синдикат);
*Все здесь загажено, все **пропитано насилием** в самой грубой и беспощадной форме* (М. Палей. Long Distance, или Славянский акцент);
*Здесь пол, стены, потолок ― все **пропитано муками, голодом, страданиями, горем, бессонницей, тоской**, давит все, душит…* (Т. Окуневская. Татьянин день);
*Пишу на солнце, и письмо **пропитано солнцем и** соленым корсиканским **ветром*** (В. Каверин. Перед зеркалом).

*Все в Москве пропитано стихами,

Рифмами проколото насквозь.*
Анна Ахматова

Comment: А как цитируемое не расматриваете? Типа: вот какое словечко от представителя прилетело!

Comment: Нет, не думаю. Политики и парламентарии уже давно используют такое сочетание. *Депутаты Государственной Думы заявляли, что процесс усыновления российских детей, который контролирует министерство образования России, «**пропитан коррупцией** и некомпетентностью», что ведѐт фактически к «продаже» российских детей* (Коррупция в сфере международного  усыновления (2013)). *В мае 1999 года заместитель министра финансов России Олег Вьюгин отмечал, что система власти и бизнеса в России во многом **пропитана коррупцией** и преступным бизнесом* (из Википедии).

Comment: Сочетание (1) такое же, почти. Там кавычки дважды встречаются. Значит ошибка? Как я понял, пример с депутатами проходит, а с Захаровой нет?

Comment: Вы меня запутали. «Пропитан коррупцией и некомпетентностью» — это цитата, а собственно слово *пропитан* оформлено **без** кавычек. Это означает, что у депутатов и в минфине — правильно (без кавычек), а в статье про Захарову — нет. Не нужны кавычки.